# How can I bundle many SVG images inside just one?

Tags: html, css, svg, optimization

It's not bad if I load an HTML page

```css
img, svg {
    background-color: #eee;
    margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <img src="circle.svg"/>
    <img src="square.svg"/>
</div>
```

with just a pair of SVG images

**circle.svg**

```
<svg
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    viewBox="0 0 400 300" width="400" height="300">
    <circle cx="200" cy="150" r="100"
        stroke="red" fill="blue" stroke-width="10" />
</svg>
```

**square.svg**

```
<svg
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    viewBox="0 0 400 300" width="400" height="300">
    <rect x="100" y="50" width="200" height="200"
        stroke="green" fill="gray" stroke-width="10" />
</svg>
```

but with over a hundred SVG images, the server gets excessively hit by requests.

One solution is to serve the static files from a dedicated server, but this only dodges the problem. The number of requests remains high.

How can I bundle many SVG images inside just one?

Comment: You can embedd them in html which makes them more accessible to css, the page size might get crazy. You can embed them in css using data strings. Finally you can embed them in JavaScript which requires a bit of programming.

Comment: You could use a SVG sprite generator to create one big file with all images aligned in it. Then you just have to call them in CSS with background image.

Comment: @gael That's what I'm after. Could you sketch/outline, just roughly, where I would start?

Comment: Please take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52427858/preloader-script-change-svg-fill-color-before-page-load/52439542#52439542although the question is asking a different thing you may use this technique.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a SVG sprite generator to create one big file with all images aligned in it.

SVG sprite generator will also generate a CSS file in which each individual SVG will be represented with a specific class.

In you HTML you just have to call each image by its class name.

A basic sprite.css could be :

```
.svg {
    background-image: url(sprite.svg) no-repeat;
}
.circle {
    background-position: top left;
    height:300px;
    width: 400px;
}
.square{
    background-position: top right;
    height:200px;
    width: 200px;
}
```

And then in your html file you could just call:

```
<div>
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure exactly how you intended to do it. Please see my draft answer and provide more details if possible. I would prefer your answer since it shows clearly that exactly one request will ever be sent to the server.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need an SVG sprite. I use this trick all the time. It's great. Just make your `svg` blocks `symbol` elements and nest them inside an `svg` like this:

```html
<svg id="svg-sprite" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <symbol id="svg-circle" viewBox="0 0 400 300" width="400" height="300">
    <circle cx="200" cy="150" r="100" stroke="red" fill="blue" stroke-width="10" />
  </symbol>

  <symbol id="svg-square" viewBox="0 0 400 300" width="400" height="300">
    <rect x="100" y="50" width="200" height="200" stroke="green" fill="gray" stroke-width="10" />
  </symbol>
</svg>
```

Note that you don't want the `xlmns` attribute on the individual `symbol` elements, just the root `svg`. And the root `svg` doesn't need a viewBox attribute, since that is encoded in the child `symbol` elements.

Then you call the symbols elsewhere in the HTML like this via the `<use>` tag:

```html
<svg>
  <use xlink:href="#svg-circle"></use>
</svg>
```

Lastly, you need to hide the sprite in CSS:

```css
#svg-sprite {
  display: none;
}
```

---

Here's a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) to demonstrate. Good luck!

Comment: If you have external .svg assets as separate files, then you'd need to run a script somewhere that injects the contents of each SVG into a single html template.

Comment: Another idea is you could convert the svg data to JSON and serve that as a a single external asset that is read into your page via javascript

Comment: After playing a bit more, it seems you were very close (the jsfiddle pointer in your answer is to the site, not to a solution), but there is no need for `display: none` and the reference must include the sprite filename. Please see my draft answer and comment/improve.

Answer (score 1):

The following is a combination of gael's and maqam7's answers, with a bug fix and some details.

First, we combine the two SVGs into one. (We write our own script, use an editor's macros, use one of the web sites that do it, or do it by hand.)

**sprite.svg**

```
<svg id="mysprite" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <symbol id="circle"
        viewBox="0 0 400 300"
        width="400" height="300">
        <circle cx="200" cy="150" r="100"
            stroke="red" fill="blue" stroke-width="10" />
    </symbol>

    <symbol id="square"
        viewBox="0 0 400 300"
        width="400" height="300">
        <rect x="100" y="50" width="200" height="200"
            stroke="green" fill="gray" stroke-width="10" />
    </symbol>
</svg>
```

When we want a circle or a square, we `use` the `xlink:href` attribute ([deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/use) but continue to use it), which will invoke a sub-sprite.

```
<div class="container">
    <svg>
        <use xlink:href="sprite.svg#circle"></use>
    </svg>
    <svg>
        <use xlink:href="sprite.svg#square"></use>
    </svg>
</div>
```

There is no need to include the sprite in the `body`

```
<img src="sprite.svg"/>
```

as the sprite is referenced within each `svg` element.

Hence there is no need to hide the global sprite.

```
#svg-sprite {
    display: none;
}
```

Only the sub-parts appear.

One caveat: Chrome loads an `img` and `svg` directly, but will refuse to load `use`/`xlink:href` unless you run a local server.

**Remaining issue(s)**

I'm not sure this is optimal. It may be that two requests continue to be sent. It's just that the cache will catch the second as identical. No harm is done. Still, loading once via a hidden `svg` may be a better approach, if someone can fill in the details.